# adView throwing Null pointer exception

Tags: android, admob

Please find the code below adView was giving nullpointerexception.

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Prepare the Interstitial Ad
            interstitial = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this);
            // Insert the Ad Unit ID
            interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6117491189465387/7628536955");

    //Locate the Banner Ad in activity_main.xml
    AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);

    // Request for Ads
    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder=new AdRequest.Builder();

    // Add a test device to show Test Ads
        adRequestBuilder .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice("abcd").build();

    // Load ads into Banner Ads


     adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-6117491189465387/7628536955");
        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());

    interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            // Call displayInterstitial() function
            displayInterstitial();
        }

    });
```

I was struck since 2 day's please let me know where I was mistaken

Comment: I have been dealing with this problem too. The reason was custom ROM. It has a "good" feature like android ad block. Maybe you have the same problem ?

Comment: have you declare your interstitial  before oncreate like :InterstitialAd interstitial

Comment: @Nitin Misra,CROSP,said ,I have edited my code by setting setContentView() now there is no error show in logcat but there is no demo app shown on screen.

Comment: post your XML as well

Answer (score 1):

I don't see your setContentView() method(). adview could be null because you either don't set the layout to use or you call setContentView() after initializing the adview. You should have this:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
```

Please post the full content of the onCreate() method, your logcat stacktrace and layout file, if I'm wrong

Comment: as u said I have missed to setContentView, but now If I run I am seeing the blank activity it was not giving any add's in the layout.

Comment: Please post your XML layout file